# html tables want to understand a better way

Tags: html, css

I have this old code:

```
<html>
<head>
<body style="text-align:center;">
<style>
#wrapper{margin:0 auto; max-width:992px;}
</style>
<div id="wrapper">
<table border="1" width="100%" height="40px">
<tr>
<td>header</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table border="1" width="100%" height="50%">
<tr>
<td width="60%">Main Data Window</td>
<td width="40%">Right Side Buttons</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table border="1" width="100%" height="43%">
<tr>
<td>Bottom Buttons</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now because table height is deprecated (so if I put DOCTYPE html in the file it breaks it) what would be a modern way to get the same result.

Basically I am wanting it the same so on all monitors and device orientations it sizes the same.

Many thanks.

Comment: Just use CSS styles to replace your deprecated attributes: width, height, border. It's valid HTML5 and works the same way.

Comment: And given that this doesn't resemble tabular data (so far as I can see from your posted HTML) consider not using a `table` for layout purposes.

Comment: The modern way to get the same result would be to use `<div>` or `<section>` or `<nav>` when appropriate instead of using `<table>`. `<table>` is only intended for tabular data (for example, a list of items in a shopping cart). Search for 'CSS vs Tables' and you will get many sources for getting started.

Comment: First, you have no code that you have tried, so basically you are asking us to convert 10 year old code for you. Next, you ask " I am wanting it the same so on all monitors and device orientations it sizes the same (sic)", so you are also asking us to not only modernize the code but ensure that is mobile device ready. Really? I guess you just get jobs and make posts on SO, hoping we'll do all the work for you. You're supposed to be asking questions here, not requesting code to convert your old websites.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best thing to do is to use CSS now. You could either no it inline with something like:

```
<table border="1" style="width:100%; height:40px; border:1px solid black;">
```

Or create yourself a class and apply it to the table.

```
.tbl1{
width:100%; 
height:40px; 
border:1px solid black;
}

<table class="tbl1">
```

Note: Using tables for the purpose of layout is also a deprecated way of doing things. Unless you are displaying actual tabular data I'd advise you use divs, spans, etc.